# hover on an element to change another

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

Can't make it work, I trying to change the style of prevProject & nextProject (text: prev / next) while hover on Proj name1 / Proj name2.

I could do this part, please see the demo.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/h2P34/1/

```
<div id="project-navigation">
    <ul>

        <li id="prevProject" class="subtitle">
            <a href="#"><p>prev</p></a>
            <a id="prev_target_title">Proj name1</a>
        </li>


        <li id="nextProject" class="subtitle">
            <a href="#"><p>next</p></a>
            <a id="next_target_title">Proj name2</a>
        </li>

    </ul>  
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h2P34/1/#&togetherjs=Kjfsh0wkiT

Comment: why U don't use id to prev and next ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done in CSS.  Your code `#prev_target_title:hover ~ #project-navigation ul li#prevProject p` will not work because tilde (~) is a general sibling selector.  The browser is looking for `#project-navigation` that follows anywhere after the `#prev_target_title` when the latter is in the hovered state.

In CSS you cannot select previous siblings and you cannot select parents.  The way to solve it is to place prev/next after the project name in the HTML code and then make their order visually different using CSS.  Then, you can highlight prev when the project name is hovered.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like

```
$("#prev_target_title").hover(function(){
    $("#prevProject a p").css("color","red");
});

$("#prev_target_title").on('mouseleave',function(){
    $("#prevProject a p").css('color','black');
});
```

But I would also use class names instead of ids

```
//changing color to red
$(".hoverClass").hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().find("a p").css("color","red");
});

//changing it back to black
$(".hoverClass").on('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).parent().find("a p").css("color","black");
});
```

We're using Jquery here, you can't do this with simple css.

Check this fiddle, I hope it helps
http://jsfiddle.net/rqg87/

As Jason points out, hover takes 2 arguments - mouseenter and mouseleave... so:

```
$(".hoverClass").hover(
    function(){ $(this).parent().find("a p").css("color","red"); },
    function(){ $(this).parent().find("a p").css("color","black");}
);
```

Optimized solution would be:
http://jsfiddle.net/P7Zbz/

Comment: Hover accepts a "mouseenter" (1st argument) and "mouseleave" parameter; a separate "mouseleave" event is unnecessary. Using a single event can increase performance (slightly) as jQuery will not need to find ".hoverClass" twice in the DOM. See http://api.jquery.com/hover/.